# Having a problem with awk to receiving string variable from xargs

Tags: awk, xargs

`ls subset/*.txt | cut -d "/" -f 2 | cut -d "." -f 1 | xargs -i awk '$2 == {} {print $3,$4 > $2}' data.txt`

Could someone pls help me why this wouldn't work?

I have a list of files in subset directory and I want to take those file names.
`ls subset/*.txt | cut -d "/" -f 2 | cut -d "." -f 1` 
This part shows that I have successfully separated the filenames.

Then I want to look for the lines in data.txt with $2 that matches the file name and save field $3 and $4  under the file names $2.

I've been trying different versions but none of them does what I want. I guess there is something I don't know about xargs -i option, but I just can't figure out. Could anyone pls help with this?

My file would inside subset directory is lets say,

file1.txt

file2.txt

file3.txt

My data.txt contains data on thousands of file, only subset of which is in the subset directory.
Each line in data.txt is one record file: for example like this.

xxxx file2 34  45 xxxx xxxx  xxxx   xxxx

xxxx file1 54  30 xxxx  xxx  xxxx    xxx

vvvd file2  23  30 xfxx flkd  sdlfkj  dfs

I just want to save field 3 and 4 separately so that output looks like this.

contents of file2.txt:

34 45

23 30

contents of file1.txt:

54 30

Comment: `ls subset/*.txt` is a bad starting point (see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can help you do what you're trying to do the right way.

Comment: Thanks for providing additional information but please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting for how to correctly format your blocks of input, output, and code or just look at how it's done in existing questions.

Answer (score 1):

Your `xargs` command didn't work because it's replacing the `{}` in the awk command with the text it's working with and so in that context that text appears to be awk variable names that were never set and so are null when you want them to be strings. To have that text be treated as a string you'd need to put the `{}` inside double quotes. Look:

```
$ printf 'foo\n' | xargs -i awk 'BEGIN{ print {} }'

$ printf 'foo\n' | xargs -i awk 'BEGIN{ print "{}" }'
foo
```

That first command is equivalent to trying to print the value of an unpopulated variable named `foo`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ print foo }'
```

while the second is what you want, to print the literal string `"foo"`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ print "foo" }
```

Without sample input/output it's a guess but it seems like this might be what you're trying to do:

```
awk '
BEGIN {
    for (; ARGC>2; ARGC--) {
        fname = ARGV[ARGC-1]
        delete ARGV[ARGC-1]
        sub(".*/","",fname)
        sub("\.[^.]+$","",fname)
        fnames[fname]
    }    
}
$2 in fnames { print $3, $4 >> $2; close($2) }
' data.txt subset/*.txt
```

That's just 1 call to awk, no `ls`, `xargs`, etc. required unless you have so many files under `subset` that you exceed your shell's max arg length.

Comment: Another excellent "Ed" answer. I was just waiting for the "Whenever I see `foo | bar | baz | awk '{...}'`, the answer is usually -- why not `awk` to begin with?" You nailed that again..

Comment: HI thanks for the codes. I'm not a serious coder haha. Just trying to scrap together what I know. I'll do my research but could someone pls explain this code to me? Especially this part: for  (; ARGC>2; ARGC--)? Is it double checking that the two files are being read?

Comment: no, it's just looping through the list of file names passed as arguments and storing all but the first file name (`data.txt`) in the `fnames[]` hash to they can be compared to the `$2`s from data.txt later. The loop is also deleting them from the arguments list as it goes so the script doesn't try to read them. You can always add print statements to dump variables, etc. to see what it's doing if reading the man page isn't enough.